# How to call method from a dynamic type of an Object inside a class?

Tags: java

**What I want to do:**

Calling some method which exists in more than one class, while substance is passed into another class.

**What I am doing :**

I have several Classes that extends 'JPanel', and all of them have common methods: `alert()` and `refresh()`.

```
public class MyView01  extends JPanel{

    public void alert(String msg){
        // do something...
    }
    public void refresh(){
        // do some other thing...
    }

}

public class MyView02  extends JPanel{

    public void alert(String msg){
        // do something...
    }
    public void refresh(){
        // do some other thing...
    }

}
```

Then I have a Class for an action which will pass a substance of my Class into it, for calling method from my Class.

```
public class MyViewAction{

    private Object view;

    public void setView(Object view){
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void someOperating(){

        int result = doSomthingElse();
        if(result == 1){
            view.refresh();
        }else{
            view.alert("The answer is 42.");
        }
    }

}
```

While `someOperating()` may be used in both classes - `MyView01`, `MyView02`. I want to use the `MyViewAction` Class to declare it (DRY). I want to pass different type of Objects into the view field, to do so, I tried "Object" type, however I can't call the method this way.

What should I change to make it work ?

Comment: Read on [`Java Polymorphism`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: Looks like your classes should implement a common interface.

Comment: I wonder it is nothing about Polymorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this by creating a common interface.

```
   public interface View {
       void alert(String msg);
   }
```

Implement the interface in both your View classes

```
public class MyView01  extends JPanel implements View{

    public void alert(String msg){
        System.out.print("From View 01 " + msg);
    }
}

class MyView02  extends JPanel implements View{

    public void alert(String msg){
        System.out.print("From view 02 " + msg);
    }

}
```

Declare an use the view as a 'View' type

public class MyViewAction{

```
    private View view;

    public void setView(View view){
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void someOperating(String msg){

        view.alert(msg);

    }

}
```

And use it...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyViewAction  myView = new MyViewAction();
        MyView01 v1 = new MyView01();
        MyView02 v2 = new MyView02();

        myView.setView(v1);
        myView.someOperating("View 1 out\n");

        myView.setView(v2);
        myView.someOperating("View 2 out\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: off topic : what if I have a method only use in MyView01 ? I know that may sounds wired, it is not for DRY, but will it be better if I have a way to put all action into MyViewAction ?

Comment: No problem but you will have to cast it to the MyView01 class first. you can check it its the right class type first.

Comment: `if(view.getClass().getName() == "com.MyCompany.MyView01") {
            ((MyView01)view).otherAlert("yo yo yo\n");
        }`